# How to get mobile login page when using facebook graph api

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api, mobile

I have a web app that authenticates via Facebook app login

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
 client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
 grant_type=client_credentials
```

that will redirect to (user is not already logged in)

https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=...

How can I get facebook to redirect to the mobile login page (m.facebook.com)?
It seems that Facebook does not take the user agent into account here.

Comment: What value do you have in your Mobile Web Url in your app settings?

Comment: I configured something like http://www.myapp.com/ in the app settings dialog. Are there any settings to configure the login page?

Comment: hmmm... myapp.com doesn't render correctly for me with either a desktop nor a mobile browser.

Comment: Ok, now I changed the login url to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth and https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth for mobile. That solved my problem! Information on a facebook user profile can then be retrieved via https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token.